# Trouble parsing orderddict in django template

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble trying to parse an orderddict in my django template.

This is an example dict:

```
OrderedDict([
  (u'header-1510123912515', '"{u\'label\': u\'label\'}"'),
  (u'input-1510215273074', '"{u\'label\': u\'Preferred Assignment Area\'}"'),
  (u'input-1510215283971', '"{u\'label\': u\'Expected Salary\'}"'),
  (u'input-1510215288135', '"{u\'label\': u\'Last Drawn Salary\'}"'),
])
```

From the above, I would want to get the content of label.

This is how I'm currently going through the dict in the template:

```
{% for form in document.forms.all %}
   {% for k,v in form.hdict.items  %}
       {% if 'header' not in k %}
            {"key": {{k}}, "label": "{{v.label}}"},
       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm able to successfully get the key, but not the values part (label).

I hope you can help me with this as I'm quite new to django. Thanks

Comment: the problem is that the value in `OrderedDict` is `str` type: `"{u'label': u'Preferred Assignment Area'}"`, you need to make it to be dict `{u'label': u'Preferred Assignment Area'}`.

Answer (score 0):

`v.label` is in a string. Change `"{{v.label}}"` to `{{v.label}}`

Comment: Hello, appreciate your answer but I seem to still be getting no values in for label.

Comment: `'"{u\'label\': u\'label\'}"'` is also a string. Remove the apostrophes and make it a dict instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep that logic out of the template and deserialize those value strings in the view or in the form where they originate from:

```
# forms.py
import json

class WhateverForm(forms.Form)  # form class of document.forms
    # ...
    def clean_dict(self)
        return {k: json.loads(v).get('label') for k, v in self.hdict.items() if 'header' not in k}

# template
{% for form in document.forms.all %}
    {% for k, v in form.clean_dict.items  %}
        {"key": {{ k }}, "label": "{{ v }}"},
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```